# Benro Tripod: Sticky Middle Column

Tags: tripod

I've recently purchased a Traveler Angel II (Aluminum) and have noticed that when I remove the middle column in order to reverse it or attach to the monopod leg, it sticks (in the beginning) when trying to put it back in its own place, so I have place my finger beneath the reel inside so that the column would move in properly. Is it normal, or is a flaw?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know whether it's normal or a flaw.

Does it interfere with your ability to use it properly?  Eg, to either transport or set it up, or to take photos?  If so, it sounds like it's something that's worth getting looked at.

If it doesn't really interfere with anything, other than being a slight annoyance, then it's up to you whether you think it's worth taking it further.  You could always contact whoever you bought it from.